# How do you say tabloid and broadsheet journalism in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario

What are some examples of tabloid and broadsheet newspapers in Spain? And also does 'la prensa del corazón' refer to tabloid journalism or other forms of journalism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"La prensa del corazón" or ["prensa rosa"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodismo_del_coraz%C3%B3n) are those magazines that inform about the lives of famous or notorious people (gossip magazine and the likes).

"Tabloid" can be translated simply as ["Tabloide"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabloide) which refers to sensationalist press. This has a boarder meaning than prensa rosa, because you can be sensationalist when talking about politics (which you wouldn't find in *prensa del corazón*) but by definition *prensa rosa* is sensationalist. Some *prensa rosa* magazines are so popular that could not be fitted under the pejorative connotations of a tabloid.

The regular *broadsheet newspapers* are referenced in Spanish as ["Periódico de gran formato"](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peri%C3%B3dico_de_gran_formato)

So we would refer to *periodismo de prensa rosa*, *periodismo sensacionalista* (o de prensa amarilla) and simply *periodismo* for the "traditional" one.

Comment: Besides, "Tabloide" doesn't necessarily have a pejorative meaning in Spanish-speaking countries: many non-sensationalist newspapers appear in tabloid format. In fact, there are no broadsheet newspapers with wide circulation in Spain (that I know of – I'm not from Spain).

Answer (score 2):

I definitely have seen more frequently the term *prensa amarilla*, literally "yellow press", sometimes also adjectived *amarillista* or "yellowist". In a few cases I have also heard *prensa barata* or "cheap press", or the use of pejorative/obscene terms.

Comment: +1 For the addition of "prensa amarilla"